# Required property not working with repeater

Tags: qt, qml

I have a component like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.15

Item {
    id: root

    property double value: 0.0

    property int core: 1

    property color progressBarColor: "black"
    property color minMaxTextColor: "black"
    property int fontSize: height - 6

//....
}
```

Now I thought it would be a good idea to make some propertis required since they are should be declared when the component is used. So I changed to this:

```
import QtQuick 2.15

Item {
    id: root

    required property double value

    required property int core

    property color progressBarColor: "black"
    property color minMaxTextColor: "black"
    property int fontSize: height - 6

//....
}
```

The Component gets called in a repeater likes this:

```
SystemInformation{
    id: sysinfo
}

Column{
    id: displayColumn


    Repeater{
        model: sysinfo.coreUtilizationsInPercent.length

        CoreUtilizationDisplay{
            width: root.elementWidth
            height: root.elementHeight
            fontSize: root.fontSize

            progressBarColor: "#3399FF" // blue
            minMaxTextColor: "blue"

            core: index + 1
            value: sysinfo.coreUtilizationsInPercent[index]
        }
    }
}
```

Now this works fine until I make the properties required. I wonder why It does not work?

If I declare it required I get this error:

```
qrc:/qml/SystemInformationDisplay.qml:57: ReferenceError: index is not defined
```

I did the same with similar components which are not in the repeater and there it works fine.

Why?

Comment: `delegate: CoreUtilizationDisplay`

Comment: Why delegate? All the other functionality was working without it.

Comment: because index works in delegate

Comment: Even with adding delegate there still comes the error as soon as I declare the properties required

Comment: @Sandro4912 I think it's a bug, report it. The delegate is irrelevant since in the case of Repeater the delegate is a [default-property](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#default-properties)

Comment: [Qt Documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-modelview.html#models) : `Note: model, index, and modelData roles are not accessible if the delegate contains required properties, unless it has also required properties with matching names.`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the qt [develop blog](https://www.qt.io/blog/new-qml-language-features-in-qt-5.15)

> And if your delegates do not contain required properties, nothing changes here. However, if they contain at least one required property, those names are not accessible anymore. Instead, you have to explicitly opt in by specifying them as required properties.

In this case you need to add the requiered property index to the component.

```
import QtQuick 2.15

Item {
    id: root

    required property double value
    required property int core

    required property int index // add it 

    property color progressBarColor: "black"
    property color minMaxTextColor: "black"
    property int fontSize: height - 6

//....
}
```

With this additional index you can build your component and have access to index. You do not need to specify index. This is done, since it is a delegate.

```
Repeater{
    model: sysinfo.coreUtilizationsInPercent.length

    delegate: CoreUtilizationDisplay{
        width: root.elementWidth
        height: root.elementHeight
        fontSize: root.fontSize

        progressBarColor: "#3399FF" // blue
        minMaxTextColor: "blue"

        core: index + 1
        value: sysinfo.coreUtilizationsInPercent[index]
    }
}
```

More informations can be found in the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-modelview.html)

Comment: thanks for the late answer. I would have never guessed that you have to add the `index` explicitly

Comment: Today I run in the same problem. I think the behavior is not intuitive.

Comment: I wasted 3 hours on this thing. Qt should definitely throw a bug in cases like this.

Comment: [Qt Documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-modelview.html#models) : `Note: model, index, and modelData roles are not accessible if the delegate contains required properties, unless it has also required properties with matching names.`